# Bound for Gamma Function Expression

Tags: integration, gamma-function

In Sobolev's [The Efimov Effect. Discrete Spectrum Asymptotics](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02096734), the following inequality is stated on page 112 $$\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{-(n+\frac{1}{2})}}{(x^2-1)^{\frac{3}{4}}}dx=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}+\frac{1}{2})\Gamma(\frac{1}{4})}{2\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}+\frac{3}{4})}\le\frac{8}{3^{\frac{3}{4}}(2n+1)^{\frac{1}{4}}},$$ where $n$ is a natural number. Using [Gautschi's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gautschi%27s_inequality) I was able to prove the looser bound $$\le\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{4})\sqrt{10}}{2(2n+1)^{\frac{1}{4}}},$$ but I can't get that one. Can anybody help me to find that out?

Comment: n is a natural number?

Comment: Yes, it is a natural number

Comment: Why is that useful? Or even better, what makes you think that is even true?

Comment: The expression with the Gamma function is equal to $$\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{-(n+\frac{1}{2})}}{(x^2-1)^{\frac{3}{4}}}\diff x$$. In an article I am reading the inequality is stated with the integral, so my first reaction was to compute the integral.

Comment: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02096734

Page 112 right after the line "Furthermore, using the inequality"

Comment: Am I mistaken or there is an excess 2 in the numerator of the Gamma functiom expression in your Desmos link?

Comment: I conjecture that the best lower bound is given by $$\frac{4\sqrt2}{3^{3/4}(2n+1)^{1/4}}$$

Comment: Is the precise asymptotic $\Gamma(s)/\Gamma(s+a)\sim s^a$ (on half-planes $\Re(s)\ge \delta>0$, from Watson's lemma) insufficient for your purposes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$
\frac{{\Gamma \left( {\frac{n}{2} + \frac{1}{2}} \right)\Gamma \left( {\frac{1}{4}} \right)}}{{\Gamma \left( {\frac{n}{2} + \frac{3}{4}} \right)}} = \int_0^1 {t^{\frac{n}{2} - \frac{1}{2}} (1 - t)^{ - \frac{3}{4}} dt}  = \int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - s\left( {\frac{n}{2} + \frac{1}{8}} \right)} s^{ - \frac{3}{4}} \left( {\frac{{s/2}}{{\sinh (s/2)}}} \right)^{\frac{3}{4}} ds} 
$$
for all $n\geq 0$. Thus,
$$
\frac{{\Gamma \left( {\frac{n}{2} + \frac{1}{2}} \right)\Gamma \left( {\frac{1}{4}} \right)}}{{\Gamma \left( {\frac{n}{2} + \frac{3}{4}} \right)}} \le \int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - s\left( {\frac{n}{2} + \frac{1}{8}} \right)} s^{ - \frac{3}{4}} ds}  = \frac{{\sqrt 2 \Gamma \left( {\frac{1}{4}} \right)}}{{\left( {2n + \frac{1}{2}} \right)^{1/4} }}
$$
for all $n\geq 0$. Finally,
$$
\frac{{\Gamma \left( {\frac{n}{2} + \frac{1}{2}} \right)\Gamma \left( {\frac{1}{4}} \right)}}{{2\Gamma \left( {\frac{n}{2} + \frac{3}{4}} \right)}} \le \frac{8}{{3^{3/4} (2n + 1)^{1/4} }}\frac{{\sqrt 2 3^{3/4} \Gamma \left( {\frac{1}{4}} \right)(2n + 1)^{1/4} }}{{16\left( {2n + \frac{1}{2}} \right)^{1/4} }} < \frac{8}{{3^{3/4} (2n + 1)^{1/4} }}
$$
for all $n\geq 0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clear answer